# Visual Studio Plugin: Insert date or version number

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, plugins, visual-sourcesafe

My company is suffering some deployment issues, where we'd be greatly benefited if distributed source files were tagged with their current source control version, or the date/time they were checked in.

Is there a way in Visual Studio to do this automatically?

Comment: What version control are you using?

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean by "tagged" exactly, putting the info current source control version, or the date/time in the head of a source file? this feature is called Keyword Expansion. you may find one VCS which supports this feature. not sure whether visual studio can do this or not without a 3rd party tool